# Get image stream from TakePhotoAsync()

Tags: xamarin

I am getting an image stream from TakePhotoAsync Method? Where do I need to change the code?

```
           await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "No camera is available!", "OK");
            return;
        }

        camreaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Small,
            //SaveToAlbum = true,
            Directory = "Sample",
            Name = "test.jpg"
        });


        //mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync();
        if (camreaFile == null)
            return;
        fileName.Text = camreaFile.AlbumPath;
        await DisplayAlert("File Location", camreaFile.Path, "OK");
        image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            var stream = camreaFile.GetStream();
            //camreaFile.Dispose();
            return stream;
        });
```

--Pass parameter for server

```
 if(mediaFile !=null)
             {
        MultipartFormDataContent content = new 
        MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Add(new StringContent(AppSetting.UserName), 
                "userId");
                     content.Add(new StringContent(remark), "remarks");
                content.Add(new StringContent(AppSetting.ConsignmentNumebr), "consignmentNo");
                content.Add(new StringContent(AppSetting.TaskId), "jobId");
               content.Add(new StreamContent(cameraFile.GetStream()),"\"file\"",$"\"{AppSetting.ConsignmentNumebr + ".png"}\"");
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                 var uploadServiceBaseAddress = "myserver/api/UploadContainerImage/";  var uploadResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAddress, content);uploadResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();          }
```

--I expect the output that successfully reaches the server.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: When I upload file to server with  this code -> content.Add(new StreamContent(cameraFile.GetStream()), "\"file\"", $"\"{AppSetting.ConsignmentNumebr + ".png"}\""); I got error cant access Dispose object.

Comment: That is because your stream will be disposed once you leave the fromStream method you will have to maintain it in another variable

Comment: Yes,.I forget to delete mediaFile.Dispose().When I delete that,I works fine.Thanks, @G.hakim for pointing me.

Comment: If you want i can add it as an answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispose of the Media file after you send it to the server to avoid this exception.

If you do that before you are sending it to the server, of course, it will give you an [ObjectDisposedException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.objectdisposedexception?view=netframework-4.7.2)

If you want to dispose of this variable just do it after the service call something like below:

```
FooServiceMethod();
mediaFile.Dispose();
```